# How to store AutoCAD data in ArcSDE database?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, dwg

Does anyone have an idea how i can create a database instance on my ArcSDE geodatabase to store my .dwg files?

I have over 1 million of these files and would be happy to automatically extract and migrate them into a specified schema in the Geodatabase.

I am using ArcSDE 10.1 on SQL Server2008 R2

Comment: Have a look at FME from Safe Software - this will do what you need and a lot more besides! http://www.safe.com

Comment: I was thinking there is a way to achieve this through scripting. I wrote a script that is able to convert the cadfiles into feature datasets and featureclasses and store them into a geodatabase. But this happens on individual file, I need a script that can do it in batches; since i have very many files to process

Comment: what language is your script in? Python?

Comment: Yes! Im using Python language

Answer (score 1):

Based on your answer to my comment I think you could probably look at writing a MS-DOS batch script to execute your Python script on your files:

```
SET SRC_DIR=<Directory of files>
SET PYTHON_EXE=<Path to Python.exe>
SET PYTHON_SCRIPT=<Path to Python Script>

FOR %%A IN %SRC_DIR%\*.dwg DO %PYTHON_EXE% <parameters for script>
```

Presumably your script will require the path to a *.dwg file to work on, so in the `<parameters for script>` part you can use `%%A` to pass in the filename of the current file in the loop. Then obviously you need to specify any other parameters your script requires to run such as Geodatabase connection settings.

Comment: HI Chanders, Thanks a lot for your help, please I have a few questions here, I dont quite understand what you mean by the geodatabase connection settings - Actually the python script i have written accesses my .dwg folder, picks up the specified file and acts on it and converts it to a feature dataset and stores it in a geodatabase. but I am only able to do this for individual file but i need it to br iterate through all the .dwg files in the speficied  folder location.

Comment: my second question is this, should i run the batch script directly from the cmd interface (tried it but it keeps giving me some syntax error). I wrote it out on a notepad and save it as pytdos.bat, and run it but im not sure if its ok

Comment: here is what I have -  SET SRC_DIR=<C:\CADdata>
SET PYTHON_EXE=<C:\Python27>
SET PYTHON_SCRIPT=<C:\Users\iegbulefu\Documents\my scripts>
FOR %%A IN %SRC_DIR%\*.dwg DO %PYTHON_EXE% <%%A>

Comment: Remove the < > as they were there to indicate where you should put your own value. That is probably why you ate getting a syntax error. Also, if any of your directory or file paths have spaces the. Make sure you enclose them in "